# How to create an associative array in typescript with a property that iterates the associative array itself

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an object, that works like an array and could have some properties that could iterate the same array:

```
interface ICustomer {
  orderId: string
  name: string
}

interface ICustomers {
  [key: number]: ICustomer
  findByOrderId: (id:string) => ICustomer
}
```

Now trying to create an example instance of `ICustomers`:

```
const customers: ICustomers = {
  0: {
    orderId: 'aaa',
    name: "Johny"
  },
  1: {
    orderId: 'bbb',
    name: "Pablo"
  },

  findByOrderId: function(id: string) {
    for (customer of this) {
      if (customer.orderId === id) {
        return customer
      }
    }

    return null
  }
}
```

It shows the following error: `Type 'ICustomers' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.(2488)`

How to implement 'Symbol.iterator' in this case? Maybe there is another approach?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-typescript-associative-array-test-5qxoz) is a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Error

In order to use `for of` you need to provide `[Symbol.iterator]`

## Fix

Add that to the interface and the implementation. Code without any errors:

```
interface ICustomer {
  orderId: string
  name: string
}

interface ICustomers {
  [key: number]: ICustomer
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => Generator<ICustomer>
  findByOrderId: (id: string) => ICustomer | null
}

const customers: ICustomers = {
  0: {
    orderId: 'aaa',
    name: "Johny"
  },
  1: {
    orderId: 'bbb',
    name: "Pablo"
  },

  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    yield this[0];
    yield this[1];
  },

  findByOrderId: function (id: string) {
    for (let customer of this) {
      if (customer.orderId === id) {
        return customer
      }
    }

    return null
  }
}
```